# Div is not moving to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#pg2_main_display_div ").css({ 
    top: -$("#pg2_main_display_div").offset().top
});
```

Here: `-$("#pg2_main_display_div").offset().top` value is -1033.

This code is not working. It is not yet all moving to top.

CSS:

```
#pg2_main_display_div #pg2_listdiv ul li a{
        left:0%;
        margin-left: 6%;
        padding-bottom: 2.8%;
        padding-top: 2.8%;
        font-size: 220%;
        color:white:
 }

 #pg2_main_display_div #pg2_listdiv img{
        font-size: 50%;
        margin-left: 5%;
        height: 40%;
        width: 4%;       
        top:44%;
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some snippets of your HTML, or better yet, put a 'working' example of your not working code into a jsFiddle?

Comment: as mentioned in above i know the moved position of that div. that is 1033. now i want to move the same div to its initial position which is 0.

Comment: You want to move it to top:0? So why not `$("#pg2_main_display_div").css({top:0});` Provided that this element has `position:absolute`

Comment: i tried same but it is showing blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a jsFiddle to try and understand your question better and maybe provide some sort of answer? Please look at this, click the button, see what it does and make your own edit of the fiddle that better reflects what you are trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/b7EMc/

HTML

```
<div id="moveMe" style="top:130px;left:200px;position:absolute;height:100px;width:200px;background-color:red;">Hello</div>
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    console.log($('#moveMe').offset().top);
    $('#moveMe').css({top:0});    
});
```

This is a really simple bit of code that has a button and a div. The div is absolutely positioned 130px from the top. When you click the button it reports its current offset from the top to the console.log and then sets the 'top' value of the div to 0. You will then see that the div moves to the top.

Comment: <div id="pg2_main_display_div">
              <div id="pg2_list_div"></div>
   </div>

Comment: i added my css and html above:   it is working but page is not at fixed position. i used position:relative.  When i used position:absolute div contents are not shown. only blank screen appeared.

Comment: You've only added your CSS to the question, can you add the actual HTML you are using so we can replicate the problem, or put it in a jsFiddle, its really easy and you don't need a user account. You can even modify the one I created to make a 'version 2' and send us that link. It looks like in your css you've got a rule for list items, but the only HTML you've shared with us is 2 empty divs.

Comment: <div data-role="content" data-scroll="y"  id="pg2_content1" data-theme="a" data-handler="true">   
   
    <div id="pg2_main_display_div">
    <div id="pg2_list_div"></div></div>
      
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this .css({"position":"fixed","top":"0px"}).

But like Rob Quincey mentioned if you want get accurate answers you mast give details of your problem.

Comment: i tried same thing but itis showing blank screen when i used position:fixed or position:absolute.

Comment: What do you mean "blank screen"? And please post your code (html, css and js)

Comment: Do you have other js or jquerry code involved? Post css rules that styles div element.